# how to perform a basic arithmetics from unix csh/tcsh shell

Tags: linux, shell, unix, csh, tcsh

Under windows, when I need to perform  a basic calculations, I use a built-in calculator. Now I would like to find out what is the common way if you only have a shell.

Thanks

Comment: I can't believe no one's proposed a Perl solution! ;-)

Comment: there also exist numerous gui-based calculators for linux. but dc or bc is fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And you can always use the python interpreter, it's normally included in linux distros.

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#using-python-as-a-calculator

```
$ python
Python 2.6.2 (r262:71605, Apr 14 2009, 22:40:02) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 2+2
4
>>> # This is a comment
... 2+2
4
>>> 2+2  # and a comment on the same line as code
4
>>> (50-5*6)/4
5
>>> # Integer division returns the floor:
... 7/3
2
>>> 7/-3
-3
>>> # use float to get floating point results.
>>> 7/3.0
2.3333333333333335
```

The equal sign ('=') is used to assign a value to a variable. Afterwards, no result is displayed before the next interactive prompt:

```
>>> width = 20
>>> height = 5*9
>>> width * height
900
```

And of course there's the [math](http://docs.python.org/library/math.html) module which should solve most of your calculator needs.

```
>>> import math
>>> math.pi
3.1415926535897931
>>> math.e
2.7182818284590451
>>> math.cos() # cosine
>>> math.sqrt()
>>> math.log()
>>> math.log10()
```

Comment: Yes, use the interactive python interpreter :-). My Dave

Comment: This question was specific about tcsh/csh. What about systems that don't have python installed?

Answer (score 20):

From [this web page](https://web.archive.org/web/20070206180858/https://decf.berkeley.edu/help/unix/csh/expressions.html) (for `csh` and derivatives, since you asked):

```
% @ x = (354 - 128 + 52 * 5 / 3)
% echo Result is $x
Result is 174
```

and

```
% set y = (354 - 128 + 52 / 3)
% echo Result is $y
Result is 354 - 128 + 52 / 3
```

notice the different results.

Personally, I stick to `/bin/sh` and call `awk` or something (for maximal portability), or others have exhibited the `bash` approach.

Comment: I never knew of '@ '!  For the reader, note that the space after the '@' is necessary.  Also, the reference is no longer valid.  It still exists in archive, though: [C Shell: Expression Syntax](https://web.archive.org/web/20150625154149/https://decf.berkeley.edu/help/unix/csh/expressions.html)

Answer (score 10):

You can use [dc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dc_(computer_program)).  Or [bc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bc_programming_language).

Comment: `dc` if you prefer RPN (Forth-like), `bc` if you prefer infix notation (C-like)

Comment: Right. (But RPN is a sacred geek creed; let us not show disrespect for it by saying it is like unto another, brother ;)

Comment: A true believer writes his prose *subject* *object* *verb* : "RPN, sacred geek creed, is."

Comment: *Subject object verb* a true believer his prose writes: "RPN, sacred geek creed, is."

Answer (score 10):

There are many good solutions given here, but the 'classic' way to do arithmetic in the shell is with `expr`:

```
$ expr 1 + 1
2
```

`expr` has a sensible return value, so that it succeeds when the expression evaluates to a non-zero value allowing code (in a Bourne shell) like:

```
$ op="1 + 1"
$ if expr $op > /dev/null; then echo "$op is not zero"; fi
1 + 1 is not zero
```

or (if using a shell that supports arrays):

```
$ op=(8 \* 3)
$ if expr "${op[@]}" > /dev/null; then echo "${op[@]} is not zero"; fi
8 * 3 is not zero
```

Note that the `if` syntax in Bourne shells is completely different than in the `csh` family, so this is slightly less useful and you need to check against the value of `#?`.

Comment: The only caveat is that, since "*" is a special character in shell, you need to escape it when doing multiplication with expr.

E.g.

     $ expr 1 + 2 * 3
     expr: syntax error
     $ expr 1 + 2 \* 3
     7

Answer (score 4):

Bash [supports basic (integer only) arithmetic](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-bash2.html#N100F3) inside `$(( ))`:

```
$ echo $(( 100 / 3 ))
33
$ myvar="56"
$ echo $(( $myvar + 12 ))
68
$ echo $(( $myvar - $myvar ))
0
$ myvar=$(( $myvar + 1 ))
$ echo $myvar
57
```

(example copied straight from the IBM link)

- [More in-depth discussion of bash arithmetic](http://bash-hackers.org/wiki/doku.php/syntax/arith_expr)

Comment: +1  And, I also use it for fixed-point non-integer questions by adding zeroes in the equation and inserting decimal points in my head. :)

Comment: Along these lines, `((...))` is similar but as a command (does not substitute result, `$?` gets set), and `$[...]` is short for `$((...))`.

Comment: `$(( ... ))` is valid syntax for all SH derived shells, e.g. Bash, Zsh. See [The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_04)

Comment: The question was specifically about tcsh/tcl.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Perl easily where bc or expr are not powerful enough:

```
$ perl5.8 -e '$a=1+2; print "$a\n"' 
3
```

Comment: the question was about csh/tcsh. it was not about perl.

Comment: @norman_h - would you mind please explaining the meaningful difference between running "perl" vs "bc" or "dc" command, neither of which are csh/tcsh builtins? Other than your Meta knowledge that Perl happens to be a powerful programming language, aside from being able to do a task like "bc" can? Also, accepted answer uses Python, so clearly that approach is perfectyly fine with OP.

Comment: For that matter, `expr` from another high voted asnwer is also NOT a csh/tcsh builtin but a separate command, like `perl`

Comment: The question explicitly heads up with tcsh/csh. Not all environments contain heavy solutions such as perl/python. Even bc/dc executables can be considered superfluous to a basic csh environment. I think of csh as c in a shell... and the current highest vote answer shows some of this syntax. FWIW, my current unix environment (that pays the bills) is tcsh and very light on with the extras, every day at work feels like its 1975.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative option is to use the built in BC command